# How to take values in a object if they match with another objects property

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following object below that i would like to iterate through and if the specific object `properties.title` is the same as any other object, take the author name and add it to a new object (i figured adding it to a new object would be easier).

business1

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -89.535,
                    34.3654
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "University, Mississippi, United States",
            "properties": {
                "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",
                "authorTitle": "Florian Mai"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    10.14,
                    54.33
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "24105, Kiel, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany",
            "properties": {
                "title": "Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation",
                "authorTitle": "Iacopo Vagliano"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    10.14,
                    54.33
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "pretend place",
            "properties": {
                "title": "new title",
                "authorTitle": "joe blogs"
            }
        }

    ],
    "properties": "",
    "authors": ""
}
```

Object i would like (improvedObj)

```
var improvedObj = {

    obj1 = {
      title:'Using Adversarial Autoencoders for Multi-Modal Automatic Playlist Continuation"',
      authorList: 'Florian Mai,Iacopo Vagliano'
    },
    obj2 = {
        title:'new title',
        authorList: 'joe blogs
  }

}
```

What i've tried

```
extractorArray = []

for(i=0; i<business1.features.length;i++){
extractorArray.push(business1.features[i].properties)
}
console.log('extractor', extractorArray)

var extractedValues = extractorArray.map((title) => (title));
var extractedAuthor = extractorArray.map((authorTitle) => (authorTitle))

    var improvedObj = {

      objList : {
        title:extractedValues,
        authorList: extractedAuthor
      }
    }
```

The above goes through each feature, take's it's properties and pushes it to the `extractorArray` (so i can use a `.map` function on it). And then at the moment my thinking isn't working since i'm just copying from the array in the object (there's nothing there in the way of if a title is the same, take it's author).

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly what you want to do. Do you want to get all objects with the same name? Or do you want to simply go through the list and check if, given an object A, another object has the same property.title than A?

Comment: the 2nd suggestion. I want to go through and if another object as the same title, take the author attached to the object. And add the title-with the authors to the new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your improved object is actually array, correct me if i am wrong. Than following should work for you

```
const authorsByBook = k.features.map(feature => feature.properties).reduce((byTitle, feature) => {
    if(!byTitle[feature.title]) byTitle[feature.title] = [];
    byTitle[feature.title].push(feature.authorTitle);
return byTitle
}, {})

const improvedObject = Object.keys(authorsByBook).map(title => ({ title, authorList: authorsByBook[title].join(',')}))
```

First part loops trough list and creates object of structure {title: authors[]}. After that based on titles breaks it into array with objects {title, }

Comment: Would it be too difficult and hacky to also get the co-ordinates as well? So in the new array there would be a collection of the co-ordinates attached just like the authors?